# Angular 4 based app takes 80% CPU time for scripting

Tags: performance, angular, primeng, angular2-changedetection

We have an NG4 based app using PrimeNG library.
And we have made a screen with 7 grids and that is highly sluggish.
So the issue with the performance is that the scripting takes 70% - 80% of time.

Any ideas on this?
It is seen that the issue is with detectChanges, it is related to change detection strategy but we could not find anything clearly describing how to get out of this.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: is this on a production build with aot?

Comment: Also interested in the question above. You also may use manual triggering of change detection.

Comment: Yeap, it is a production build. In dev mode it is almost not usable. Not sure what is aot

Comment: @Damask If you are using CLI prod is always aot. Could you show the code? Template and component.